# How to deal with end of options -- in getopts

Tags: bash, getopts

I use getopts to parse arguments in bash scripts as

```
while getopts ":hd:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    d ) echo "directory = $OPTARG"; mydir="$OPTARG"; shift $((OPTIND-1)); OPTIND=1 ;;
    h ) helptext
      graceful_exit ;;
    * ) usage
      clean_up
      exit 1
  esac
done

exeparams="$*"
```

`exeparams` will hold any unparsed options/arguments. Since I want to use exeparams to hold options for a command to be executed within the script (which can overlap with the scripts own options), I want to use -- to end the options passed to the script. If I pass e.g.

```
myscript -d myscriptparam -- -d internalparam
```

`exeparams` will hold

```
-- -d internalparam
```

I now want to remove the leading `--` to pass these arguments to the internal command. Is there an elegant way to do this or can I obtain a string which holds just the remainder without `--` from getopts?

Comment: Putting `shift; OPTIND=1` inside the `getopts` loop is probably not the best way to do it.  It only works in your case because you only have 2 options and in all the other ones you just exit the script.  Otherwise you'd need `shift; OPTIND=1` in every option, which means duplicate code (bad practice).  Just do a `shift $((OPTIND - 1))` immediately after the end of the loop - this is the most conventional way and probably the most efficient as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
# ... getopts processing ...

[[ $1 = "--" ]] && shift
exeparams=("$@")
```

Note, you should use an array to hold the parameters. That will properly handle any arguments containing whitespace. Dereference the array with `"${exeparams[@]}"`

Comment: This assumes that there are no arguments between the end of options and `--`, i.e. `script foo -- bar` would pass `foo -- bar` to the external program.  My answer doesn't make that assumption as it wasn't explicitly stated in the question.

Comment: Except where the OP says "I now want to remove the *leading* --"

Comment: That was for the example `-- -d internalparams`.  In any case my answer is general enough to handle either case.

Answer (score 16):

Use the built-in `shift`.  First, do the normal `getopts` for your script.  Once that loop completes,

```
shift "$((OPTIND - 1))"
```

will shift out all the already processed options.

From there, you'll have to finish processing the non-option arguments, if any, to the first part of the script (before the `--`).  Once you encounter the `--`, shift it out until only the latter portion remains (the `-d internalparam` part that comes after `--`).  One way to do this (using `bash` syntax):

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    # process next argument
    case $1 in
    foo) # process foo
    ;;
    --) shift; break;; # found '--', discard it and exit loop
    *) # handle unrecognized argument
    ;;
    esac
    # not '--', so discard the argument and continue
    shift
done
```

Finally, only the second set of options / arguments remain, which you can pass on.  Do *NOT* use `$*` to pass the remaining parameters to another command.  Use `"$@"` instead, which preserves the original word splitting.

```
external_command "$@"
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! But how exactly do I find `--`?